# Blank screen on Xamarin Forms app using Dotfuscator

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

Im using dotfuscator only to enable root check.
My app only opens and works fine in debug mode(the root check works here). In release mode the app opens with a blank screen and I don't see any errors in debug or in device's log. Appears obfuscation is causing this bug. Is that a common bug?

This is my config file from dotfuscator

'''

```
<!--This config file was generated by Dotfuscator. Please use the Dotfuscator Config Editor to modify.-->
<!DOCTYPE dotfuscator SYSTEM "http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/dtd/dotfuscator_v2.5.dtd">
<dotfuscator version="2.3">
  <propertylist>
    <property name="InDir" value="obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin" />
    <property name="OutDir" value="obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout" />
    <property name="ReportDir" value="DotfuscatorReports\Release" />
  </propertylist>
  <global>
    <option>monocompat</option>
  </global>
  <input>
    <loadpaths />
    <asmlist>
      <inputassembly refid="525d7239-3ab4-4ea6-954e-91cfa333be3a">
        <file dir="${configdir}\${InDir}" name="MyApp.Android.dll" />
      </inputassembly>
      <inputassembly refid="560830ae-38b5-44f7-8d8c-bbfb8cf9f0ed">
        <file dir="${configdir}\${InDir}" name="MyApp.dll" />
      </inputassembly>
    </asmlist>
  </input>
  <output>
    <file dir="${configdir}\${OutDir}" />
  </output>
  <renaming>
    <option>xmlserialization</option>
    <excludelist>
      <assembly>
        <file dir="" name="MyApp.Android.dll" />
      </assembly>
      <assembly>
        <file dir="" name="MyApp.dll" />
      </assembly>
    </excludelist>
    <mapping>
      <mapoutput overwrite="true">
        <file dir="${configdir}\${ReportDir}" name="Renaming.xml" />
      </mapoutput>
    </mapping>
    <referencerulelist>
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{KeyHere}" />
    </referencerulelist>
  </renaming>
  <sos />
  <extattributes>
    <extattribute name="PreEmptive.Attributes.RootCheckAttribute">
      <type name="MyApp.Views.Messages.Carregando">
        <method name="OnAppearing" signature="void()" />
      </type>
      <propertylist>
        <property name="Action" value="Exit" />
        <property name="ActionProbability" value="1" />
        <property name="ApplicationNotificationSinkName" value="DisableIfCompromised" />
        <property name="ApplicationNotificationSinkOwner" value="MyApp.App" />
        <property name="ApplicationNotificationSinkElement" value="Method" />
      </propertylist>
    </extattribute>
  </extattributes>
  <smartobfuscation>
    <smartobfuscationreport verbosity="all" overwrite="true">
      <file dir="${configdir}\${ReportDir}" name="SmartObfuscation.xml" />
    </smartobfuscationreport>
  </smartobfuscation>
</dotfuscator>
```

'''

Thanks For Helping